# Installing SAP Business One server components in Linux GUI terminal error

Tags: suse, sapb1

I am trying to install SAP Business One version 10 server components in Linux GUI terminal error.
This is SUSE Linux SP 15.

This is the error I am getting:

```
Log File Path:/var/log/SAPBusinessOne/B1Installer_202302071140.log
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.HeadlessException: 
No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:208)
    at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:536)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:420)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:385)
    at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:189)
    at com.sap.businessone.installer.wizard.collector.gui.swing.InstallWizardFrame.<init>(InstallWizardFrame.java:56)
    at com.sap.businessone.installer.wizard.InstallWizard.lambda$new$0(InstallWizard.java:58)
    at com.sap.businessone.installer.wizard.InstallWizard.lambda$getMainUI$1(InstallWizard.java:93)
    at java.util.Map.computeIfAbsent(Map.java:957)
    at com.sap.businesson
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message says, it wants access to a X11 session.

Try `ssh -X user@remotehost` to enable X11 forwarding.

I guess there is enough documentation from SAP available how it needs to be installed in an environment that lacks X11.